# In React Native, is there a way to make a deeply nested element a full-screen element?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, nested, css-position

I have a React Native Expo app in which I'd like to make an element full-screen with essentially the following styles:

```
{
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0
}
```

The problem is, I want to do this for an element that is **deeply nested** within the structure of my screen. As a simplified example, the structure of my current screen is something like the following:

```
<View>
    <View>
        <View>
            <ComponentA>
                <ComponentB>
                    <ComponentC>
                    </ComponentC>
                    <ComponentC>
                    </ComponentC>
                    <ComponentC>
                    </ComponentC>
                </ComponentB>
            </ComponentA>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

What I want to do is set up something in `ComponentC` so that when you tap a button in that component, it causes an element within that same component to display full-screen.

Apparently though, in React Native, all elements are `position: relative` by default. As such, when I apply the styles above to the element I want to be full-screen in `ComponentC`, it doesn't show up as full-screen, but rather as filling the entirety of that particular `ComponentC` only.

Is there any way to get around this? I was thinking about taking the part of `ComponentC` that I want to have full-screen and placing it outside of `ComponentC` and at the top of my screen structure, but then, it's completely separated from `ComponentC` itself, and then I'd have to also coordinate that separate element so that it works with all of the various `ComponentC`s on the screen. Also, when I tried doing that, I ran into a bunch of issues with trying to properly maintain state.

Maybe I'm just taking the wrong approach to begin with, but is there a way to get what I want with some simple styling so that a deeply nested element can still be displayed full-screen, or am I going to have to engineer some complex thing to do what I want, and if it's the latter, any recommendations on how to approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To show something full screen no matter where you are in the hierarchy, you can use the `Modal` component: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.

Note: this solution will not work out-of-the-box if you want the relatively positioned element to fluidly transition into full screen (so-called hero or shared-element transition) - not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: Marek, thanks for the response. After messing around with it quite a bit, I ended up splitting the component into two pieces and using a simple event bus to communicate between the two. Took a bit of work, but gives the exact effect I was looking for. I do wish React Native had some sort of `position: fixed` option though.

Comment: Note - this also won't work if you're using react-native-web.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split your component, you can communicate from ComponentC to the top component directly with DeviceEventEmitter

in ComponentC:

```
import {
  DeviceEventEmitter
} from 'react-native'
```

In the function which handle the onPress action of your button you can call DeviceEventEmitter like that:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('whateverName', { myData: {} })
```

Then in the top component

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('whateverName', (myData) => );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, CR7. I didn't know that was built into React Native, but I created my own event bus that does exactly the same thing, and that's how I solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @HartleySan you're welcome ! Indeed it's not in the react native documentation :D